# reduce if statements when checking result

Tags: c++, if-statement

My C++ function has many if statements checking the returning value of called functions:

```
Result func(...){

   if (SUCCESS != func1(...))
      return ERROR;

   // do something

   if ( SUCCESS != func2(...))
      return ERROR;

   // do something else

   if (SUCCESS != func3(...))
      return ERROR;

    // do something
   .
   .
   .

}
```

Is there anyway for eliminating or reducing the if statements here?
For example I want something like this:

```
Result func(...){

   Result result = SUCCESS;
   when (result != SUCCESS) return ERROR;
   result = func1(...);
   // do something
   result = func2(...);
   // do something else
   result = func3(...);
   // do something
   .
   .
   .

}
```

Comment: Why not use exceptions?

Comment: Because the API that I'm calling does not use exceptions

Comment: You can call the function indirectly ala `X(funcN(...))`, where `X` captures the returned value and throws or returns if there's been an error.  An `inline` function is possible, or a macro....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are coding in C++, not in C, the option of throwing exceptions is available to you. Making the code look better while responding to exceptional situations properly was the primary driving force behind the feature.

In situations when you use third-party APIs that do not offer exceptions you could wrap their functions into your functions that throw exceptions, like this:

```
void func1w(...) {
    if (SUCCESS!=func1(...)) throw my_exception();
}
void func2w(...) {
    if (SUCCESS!=func2(...)) throw my_exception();
}
...
void caller() {
    try {
        func1w();
        func2w();
        func3w();
    } catch (my_exception& e) {
        cerr << "Error!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Note that the function that calls exception-throwing wrappers could stay away from checking exception codes altogether, letting the higher-level function deal with them. The general rule with exceptions is that the code should not catch exceptions unless it knows how to handle them.

You can also define a macro:

```
#define MUST_SUCCEED(x) if(SUCCESS!=(x))return ERROR
```

This comes at the cost of reduced readability, because the macro is not instantly familiar to the readers of your code:

```
MUST_SUCCEED(func1(...));
MUST_SUCCEED(func2(...));
MUST_SUCCEED(func3(...));
```

Comment: ...you can even use a macro to create the wrapper functions...! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

I cannot help myself, but to write solution which might be considered over-engineering, but it allows to prepare single template class for all results (for future use) and then minimize code for actual usage (no need to use checking methods or macros, no need to write own wrappers except this single result holder template class). Enjoy :D.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Result
{
public:

    Result() :
        m_value(),
        m_badValue()
    {

    }

    Result(const T& value, const T& badValue) :
        m_value(value),
        m_badValue(badValue)
    {

    }

    void operator=(const T& value)
    {
        if(value == m_badValue)
        {
            throw "Bad Value!";
        }
        else
        {
            m_value = value;
        }
    }

    operator const T&() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    const T& value() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }

private:

    T m_value;
    T m_badValue;
};

static const int SUCCESS = 0;
static const int FAIL = -1;

int func1()
{
    return SUCCESS;
}

int func2()
{
    return SUCCESS;
}

int func3()
{
    return FAIL;
}

int main()
{
    Result<int> result(FAIL, FAIL);

    try
    {
        result = func1();
        result = func2();
        result = func3();
    }
    catch (const char *error)
    {
        ::std::cout << "Error: " << error << ::std::endl;
    }

    ::std::cout << "Last value: " << static_cast<int>(result) << " - " <<
        ((result == SUCCESS) ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL") << ::std::endl;
}
```

Note: you should throw only what derives from `::std::exception`, but I used `const char*` to simplify things and prepare working example.

Comment: I was just about to post something *very* similar, so you get a +1 instead.

Comment: This is really a great solution!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no

Long answer: no, that's how you do it in every structured programming language that I'm aware of.

Alternative: if all functions involved (`func1`, `func2`, `func3`) would throw exceptions instead of returning a status code then you wouldn't have to use ifs. Your function `func` would just propagate any exception that was thrown from within it.

Edit, expanding on Tony's comment:

Alternative #2: involved functions do not throw exceptions, but your function could. Suppose you have a helper function like this:

```
void CheckResult(Result result)
{
    if (result != SUCCESS)
        throw SomeException(result);
}
```

Your function would then look like this:

```
void func(...)
{
    CheckResult(func1(...));
    // do something
    CheckResult(func2(...));
    // do something else
    CheckResult(func3(...));
    // do something
}
```

So, the `if`'s are not avoided but moved to another function, so that your function is free of them.

Comment: Actually, your answer is also perfect for me... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could make a vector of function pointers containing func1(), func2() etc., then iterate through all the elements in this vector by means of for loop, calling each function and comparing the value returned against SUCCESS. Then, if the return value of any function does not equal SUCCESS, you can set a flag to a value indicating error (in your example this flag would be of the name 'result').

Comment: Problem is that `func1()`, `func2()` etc. might have different arguments. At the end, this solution would work only in really special cases. Also, you often need to process the results before calling next `funcX()`. OP's question indicates that both are his case...